# .bashrc not being run despite being sourced in .bash_profile and .profile on Mac/iTerm2

Tags: bash, iterm2

.bash_profile **and** .profile contain:
`[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc`

To get things working when opening a new terminal or tab, I have to manually run:
`$ source ~/.bashrc`

```
$ $BASH_VERSION
```

Yields a blank line.

Happy to delete if this is a dumb question.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: @Kahn `$ /bin/zsh`

Comment: macos comes with zsh as the default shell now

Comment: @jesse_b yep, that was the change -- new job, new macos version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, `zsh` is getting in the way as you **may** have installed `Oh-my-zsh` at some point. You should be able to configure `~/.zshrc` and add `source ~/.bash_profile` to it.

Just to clarify, it was pointed out in the comments that zsh is installed as the default shell in MacOS now.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks!